# appcelerator module for existing ios project sdk

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I want to use into my `titanium` project the functionalities provided by an existing sdk ([deezer sdk](http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/ios)).

I know I must deal with `modules`, so I found a lot of tutorials that explain well [how to create a `titanium module` from scratch.](https://www.google.it/search?q=how%20to%20create%20a%20titanium%20module&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3ait%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr) But I didn't find something about to explain how to "wrap" an existing ios project within a titanium module. I just need the login/signup functionality and to retrieve the logged user (functionalities provided by the deezer ios sdk, of course).

can anybody help me on how to proceed?

thanks in advance
Dario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the vanilla module, you have to include the framework you are wrapping (so deezer SDK) inside the bundle. [Then follow these steps](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide-section-29004946_iOSModuleDevelopmentGuide-AddingSpecialCompilerDirectives) to add the framework to the compiler directives. Essentially you just add this:

> OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework DeezerSDK

To the module.xconfig file. Just check what the exact name is of the SDK.

After that, you can use the DeezerSDK just like you would in regular native Xcode development.

**EDIT:**

If the library is just a *.a file, then you can model what [Titanium did for the Google Admob](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/admob/mobile/ios) module. Its best to just inspect their project, bt essentially all that you need to do is create the vanilla titanium module, drop in the *.a file, and the headers, and then use it just like a native project.

Comment: but deezer sdk doesn't come as a framework. there is an ios sample project and a libDeezer.a with all headers/resources files. could I treat the sample .xcodeproj file as the framework you mentioned? so that I would import the xcodeproj file in the module project. or should I have to create the framework ?

Comment: Nope, that makes it easier then, just add in  libDeezer.a and the header files, and you shold be good to go.

Comment: the problem is that in the sample project, I have the login process that is what I am looking for. all the views and logics are already prepared. of course I could make by myself, but you know, it's already done. anyway, I will try.

Comment: Sounds like your Titanium directory cannot be found, make sure you have it pointing to the correct directory, should be `~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/` or whatever your version is

Comment: yes. in the meantime, I solved it. Now the problem seems to be the `OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -llibDeezer` that I added to the module.config file. running the app, it gives me the follow error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DeezerConnect", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcom.deezer.ios.a(ComDeezerIosModule.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

it seems like I should compile also the `.h`files, but I can't find anything that help me on the internet

Comment: Ok.solved! I forgot to check(select) the targets when adding the deezer files in the module. Anyway I created a deezer ios framework given the .a and .h files. +1 for you for the help.thanks

Comment: Hm. All of the modules I've seen also have ".m" files. What if I only have ".h" files and one ".a" file? I checked admob since you used them as an example for if you only have a ".a" file, but that also has ".m" files. (trying to make a Ti module of the webtrendssdk from here: https://github.com/Webtrends/ios-sdk)